# Low FPS and Blender Crashing

Tags: rendering

To make it short, im getting low fps in the viewport, tried various tricks/options to increase the fps, but nothing worked.
The moment i try to change the pose of a rigged character, Blender goes down to like 4-5fps, trying to play an animation in the viewport also reduces the fps to 4-5.
Trying to move a keyframe in the anmation window or pressing a shortcut to move an object (r or g) results in Blender closing on its own.
Doesnt matter what kind of character model im using, it just crashes.

Crash Log:
https://textdoc.co/cUGN1Zt0pP6ke3XE

16gb ram
nvidia geforce rtx3070
Intel i7-8700 CPU, 3.20GHz
running on windows 10

Comment: How many vertices are you trying to animate?

Comment: the model that i posted the crash log has around 45k vertices

Comment: That's not that much, are you using modifiers? Such as subdivision?

Comment: No, no modifiers, also im displaying the model in solid mode, so no heavy texture or anything

Comment: yes, the LOG says that when it's trying to draw the curves, it finds an error on a graphical library and crashes. Please share your machine specs. It's most likely you need to update GPU drivers, or something related to RAM, hence you experience sluggishness on the viewport until the point of crash.

Comment: just checked, both the game ready driver and studio driver are uptodate
i listed the specs in my initial post, do you need more informations ?